# Drag and Drop Image at particular position

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, save, android-relativelayout

In my android project I have 50 small images that need to be dragged and dropped in three big images.I set that three big images as the background of three different relative layouts.Now I want to restrict the dropped area in all three big images and also want to get the dropped place which will be later used when user came to the same page next time.I dont know how to begin and where to begin?Can anyone help me?I want the dropped place and also restrict the place of dropped....

Thanks!!

Comment: https://github.com/2dwarfs/MultiTouchControllerTutorial

Comment: http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/drag-and-drop-ui-element/      http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/drag-and-drop/android-drag-and-drop-example/

Comment: @DigveshPatel I want to restrict the area of the image to be dropped and also want to get x and y axis where the image to be dropped